# PHP to xls file and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, header, xls

```
$filename = "file.xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$content = "asd";
echo $content;
```

If  `$content`  contains some unicode symbols, in excel file, result is something like this : `áƒáƒ¡áƒ“`

How to solve this? How to set this php file `UTF8` encoding ?

I am trying: `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");` but not works

Comment: Best solution is to create a real Excel BIFF-format .xls file rather than simply echoing strings and trusting that PHP's automagic extension is enabled

Comment: echo utf8_encode($content)

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating file by simply echoing strings, you should create it as xml then doing an echo you need to add encoding to file.

`$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'`

You need to create your file in xml as its expected.
Ex:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

 <Worksheet>

<Table>

<Row>

<Cell><Data>$content</Data></Cell>

</Row>

</Table>

</Worksheet>

</Workbook>`

Comment: Note that this still isn't an xls file: it's SpreadsheetML, a format introduced in Excel2003 as an XML-based alternative to the binary BIFF .xls format